# Using Canvas zu display a picture on x/y position

Tags: java, android, canvas

I currently started to program android using the Android Studio IDE.
At the moment I try to place a picture at a x/y position.
But I always get a NULL Pointer Exception.

Code:

```
package main.com.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class main extends ActionBarActivity {
    Canvas canvas;
    public int x=50,y=20, i=0;
    public Bitmap picture;
    public Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.picture);

        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    //@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(picture,x,y,null);
    }

    public void press(View button){

            int red = rand.nextInt(255);
            int green = rand.nextInt(255);
            int blue = rand.nextInt(255);
            i++;


            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            onDraw(canvas);

            tv.setText("Test "+i);
            button1.setText("test");
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue));

    }
}
```

Logfile

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

 at main.com.test.main.onDraw(main.java:57)

 at main.com.test.main.press(main.java:70)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)

 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)

 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)

 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
```

I just don't understand how to draw a picture on a canvas.
I hope you guys can help me and I appreciate every kind of help you can give me.

Comment: Initialize the `canvas` instance variable.

Comment: I did that now and at least the app doesn't crash anymore but I somehow still can't display the picture